# Vue-Multiselect and Laravel 5.3 options show up as JSON element

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Laravel 5.3 app and using vue-multiselect (Version 2.0.0-beta13) for displaying `multiple` selects. The select's options are fetched via an AJAX GET call to a given route (shortened for readability).

```
[
    {
        "address1": "-",
        "address2": "-",
        "city": "-",
        "company": "-",
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "address1": "Adresse 1 und so",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "Wien",
        "company": "Abernathy company",   
        "id": 27
    }
]
```

This seems to be valid json, when inspecting with Chrome's network tab everything seems to be fine.

I have this Code in my Vue component:

```
<multiselect
    v-model="companyIDs"
    :allow-empty="true" 
    :value="selected"
    :multiple="true"
    :close-on-select="false"
    :label="company"
    :track-by="id"
    :options="companies"
>
</multiselect>
```

And this is a screenhsot of how the options (`companies`) get shown in the select:
[image: screenshot of the Multiselect]

What's wrong here?

Comment: So you are fetching data from JSON and store them in `companies` ? Did you parsed those data as JSON - `JSON.parse()` (I don't know if there is something similar in jQuery) ?

Comment: I am fetching data AS JSON, no need to parse it. A `typeof companies` returns `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove two `:` from your code, following should work:

```
<multiselect
    v-model="companyIDs"
    :allow-empty="true" 
    :value="selected"
    :multiple="true"
    :close-on-select="false"
    label="company"
    track-by="id"
    :options="companies"
>
```

When you add `:` before an attribute: that is [shortcut](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) for [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) and vue starts to expect that as vue [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) variable instead of simple string. As it seems you want it to be plain string and not a vue variable. so thats the root cause for the error.

Comment: THANK YOU - that didi it, shame on me for not reading the docs properly :-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `options` is the whole array of objects received as API response. If you want to show just company names, you have to pick out those before using them as values. But that is cumbersome and might feel like a hack and luckily, Vue-Multiselect authors have thought of that, so they have added features to use array of objects ([documentation](https://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/#sub-single-select-object)). The two options are `label` and `track-by`. What you did is use `:track-by` and `:label`, which is not the same thing and hence not recognized by the library.

Again, because you haven't explained what exactly are you trying to display, I'm assuming you only want to show `object[i].company` for each object in the list. In this case, you can add `label="company"` and `track-by="id"` to the component markup.

If you have more complicated logic of what you want to display as UI options, you'll have to map the array of objects received as API response into an array of strings which you want to display to the user.

Comment: You have `:track-by`. If you take at closer look at the documentation, it's used without leading `:`.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Reading  the docs properly always helps ;-)